# How to get GameObject references

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi i was wondering if there are other ways to set a GameObject active through code in c#

the only one i know is to do this:

```
public GameObject box;    
box.SetActive(true);
```

which really great, you can just drop of the object on the inspector but i was wondering if there are other ways

like using a specific name of an object or turning GameObjects into active with a certain tag. I'm having a hard time trying to find an example whenever i google it or maybe i'm searching it wrong

any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at the [GameObject API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) or the [Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ControllingGameObjectsComponents.html)?

There are [Find](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html), [FindWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html), [FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html)

or also methods like [GetComponentInChildren](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html), [FindObjectOfType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html), [FindObjectsOfType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) 

(those you can use to find a certain type of component and thereby there according `gameObject` you can than set (in)active)

but since you requested activateing multiple objects by tag:

```
var targetObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("YourTag");
foreach(var obj in targetObjects)
{
    obj.SetActive(true);
}
```

---

note however that this is a lot more expensive than having the references from the inspector. So in general try to avoid using these `FindXY` methods if possible.

And yes how remy_rm pointed out correctly in the comments you definitely should not use them in any update loops, or other methods that get called regularly. You should always call them e.g. in `Awake`, `Start` etc and store the references for later

---

**Update**

If I understand your comment correctly you additionally have some children in those tagged objects that you also want to set active:

```
var targetObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("YourTag");
foreach(var obj in targetObjects)
{
    obj.SetActive(true);
    // also activate all children
    foreach(Transform child in obj.transform)
    {
        child.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This, i would however like to emphasize on one particulair thing regarding the "find" methods. (which is also in the docs, but often overlooked). And that is that they are *terrible* performance wise, and they should be used with some slight caution. So not in update loops, or other methods that get called regularly. Exception being FindGameObjectsWithTag. so either cache the results or go for referencing from the inspector edit: i see you beat me to adding this ^^

Comment: @remy_rm yes that's what I ment saying `note however that this is a lot more expensive than having the references from the inspector. So in general try to avoid using these FindXY methods if possible.` but I tried to also add your comment to the answer

Comment: thank you but i have one more question, has to always be active what about its child that's not active? do i do the same thing?

Comment: @Furvus what do you mean exactly? You want to activate children of an object?

Comment: @Furvus most of those methods have an overload to include inactive game objects.